# Plot outliers using matplotlib and seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have performed outlier detection on some entrance sensor data for a shopping mall. I want create one plot for each entrance and highlight the observations that are outliers (which are marked by True in the *outlier* column in the dataframe).

Here is a small snippet of the data for two entrances and a time span of six days:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   "mall": ["Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1"],
                   "entrance": ["West", "West","West","West","West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "East", "East"],
                   "in": [132, 140, 163, 142, 133, 150, 240, 250, 233, 234, 2000, 222],
                   "outlier": [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False]})
```

In order to create several plots (there are twenty entrances in the full data), I have come across lmplot in seaborn.

```
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
for i, group in df.groupby('entrance'):
    sns.lmplot(x="date", y="in", data=group, fit_reg=False, hue = "entrance")
    #pseudo code
    #for the rows that have an outlier (outlier = True) create a red dot for that observation
plt.show()
```

There are two things I would like to accomplish here:

1. Lineplot instead of scatterplot. I have not been successful in using sns.lineplot for creating separate plots for each entrance, as it seems lmplot is more fit for this.
2. For each entrance plot, I would like show which of the observations that are outliers, preferably as a red dot. I have tried writing some pseudo code in my plotting attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `seaborn.lmplot` is a `Facetgrid`, which I think is more difficult to use, in this case.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

for i, group in df.groupby(['entrance']):

    # plot all the values as a lineplot
    sns.lineplot(x="date", y="in", data=group)
    
    # select the data when outlier is True and plot it
    data_t = group[group.outlier == True]
    sns.scatterplot(x="date", y="in", data=data_t, c=['r'])

    # add a title using the value from the groupby
    plt.title(f'Entrance: {i}')
    
    # show the plot here, not outside the loop
    plt.show()
```

[image]

### Alternate option

- This option will allow for setting the number of columns and rows of a figure

```py
import math

# specify the number of columns to plot
ncols = 2

# determine the number of rows, even if there's an odd number of unique entrances
nrows = math.ceil(len(df.entrance.unique()) / ncols)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=ncols, nrows=nrows, figsize=(16, 16))

# extract the axes into an nx1 array, which is easier to index with idx.
axes = axes.ravel()

for idx, (i, group) in enumerate(df.groupby(['entrance'])):

    # plot all the values as a lineplot
    sns.lineplot(x="date", y="in", data=group, ax=axes[idx])
    
    # select the data when outlier is True and plot it
    data_t = group[group.outlier == True]
    sns.scatterplot(x="date", y="in", data=data_t, c=['r'], ax=axes[idx])
    axes[idx].set_title(f'Entrance: {i}')
```

Comment: @torkestativ `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: aah, thank you! I wrongly imported it as "import matplotlib as plt"

Comment: @torkestativ I added an alternate option which will allow you to specify the rows and columns of the figures instead of plotting just one plot after the other.

Comment: That is quite useful for the large amount of plots the full data set produces. My fingers were getting tired from all the scrolling.Thank you for taking your time with this:)

Comment: @torkestativ You're welcome. Glad this works for you.